# django-allauth HTML email not send

Tags: django, django-allauth

I add in my templates folder the following subfolders and files in order to override email messages (following docs https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth#sending-e-mail)a :

```
templates/
   account/
     email/
       email_confirmation_message.html
       email_confirmation_message.txt
       email_confirmation_subject.txt
```

The override works perfectly for *.txt version of email (meaning, I think, I have a correct folder structure) **but my problem is the HTML version is not send over by django_allauth.**

Comment: What version are you using (HTML mails are 0.10+)? Otherwise, I suggest you step through this code: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/052e500965f1e9913c51587f6d9f115ccb3bb21d/allauth/account/adapter.py#L67 to see why things are not being picked up -- your directory structure looks fine.

Comment: I am using version 0.11.1. I've read the source but not 'that' thoroughly. I'll read gain. Thanks

Comment: Ok, it turns out that the piece of source code involved is, in fact, the following :
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/052e500965f1e9913c51587f6d9f115ccb3bb21d/allauth/account/models.py#L120

If I read carefully the doc it is not mentionned that django_allauth makes a difference between newly registered user or not when it comes to email registration messages.

I'll continue my tests, I guess I need 6 templates then (email_confirmation_signup* and email_confirmation*)

Comment: Ok I figured out the whole thing. Clear and easy now. Was really tired yesterday, didn't pay enough attention.
What's unclear for me is that my overrided version of email_confirmation_message.txt was send during my test (and not the source version email_confirmation_signup_message.txt)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For those facing the same issue :

When it comes to email confirmation django_allauth checks if its a new user or not and looks for template accordingly :

So you'll have to override :

```
email_confirmation_message.txt
email_confirmation_signup_message.txt
```

and add HTML version

```
email_confirmation_message.html
email_confirmation_signup_message.html
```

Comment: Also, I had to change the file extension to `.html` inside the file `email_confirmation_signup_message.html`: `{% include "account/email/email_confirmation_message.html" %}`

Comment: What about the {{ user }} and {{ confirmation link }}, How do i add these to the custom template?